# Avoid certain files using Directory.GetFiles in a List

Tags: vb.net, image

In this app I am working on the user selects a subfile name from a combobox and within that subfolder are a max of 5 pictures (at the start). The names of those images are what ever the camera outputs them as, meaning I don't know the file names. The purpose of this app is to let the user preview the 1-5 images in small thumbnail pictureboxes then select one at a time and save them using text strings from radiobuttons options, after pushing a "rename" button the code then save the selected image as the name selected.

All that works, but I have 2 issues.

1st. Once the images are saved there are now more then 5 jpeg pictures in the folder, These pictures that are being saved will always contain these words:

*PicSpindle, PicRotorTop, PicRotorBottom, PicDunnageFinal,or PicDunnageLayer*

So is there a way to avoid jpeg files with those strings in the `Directory.GetFiles` using my code I already have? There is probably a better way of doing this but this is all I could put together with my knowledge. maybe use `file.move` or replacing the images somehow instead of saving the images as a new name and adding more jpeg file to the folder?

2nd is once I know how to exclude the above string in jpeg `getfile` names I need to release and delete all the old files using a "Purge pictures" button I will add.

I got some of this code online and have been cobbling it together all day. But now I've hit a road block and cant find anything that will help me past this point.

Code:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Dim Pictype As String
Private HighlightedPictureBox As PictureBox = Nothing
Private Sub cmbPartNumber_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbPartNumber.TextChanged
    Dim FileName As String = cmbPartNumber.Text
    lblRenameAs.Text = Pictype & FileName
    Label1.Visible = True
    picPreview1.Visible = True
    picPreview2.Visible = True
    picPreview3.Visible = True
    picPreview4.Visible = True
    picPreview5.Visible = True
    Picture_Preview()
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim Folder = From dir In IO.Directory.GetDirectories("\\HOMESHARE01\Public\Reference Cards\Completed Reference Cards by Part Number")
                 Select IO.Path.GetFileName(dir)

    cmbPartNumber.Items.AddRange(Folder.ToArray)
End Sub

Private Sub btnSavePic_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSavePic.Click
    Dim FileName As String = cmbPartNumber.Text
    'Check if no radio button checked
    If Not (radSpindle.Checked = True Or radRotorTop.Checked = True Or radRotorBottom.Checked = True Or radDunnageFinal.Checked = True Or radDunnageLayer.Checked = True) Then
        MsgBox("Please Select Picture Type Before Renaming")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Check which radio button is checked
    If radSpindle.Checked = True Then
        Pictype = "PicSpindle"
    End If
    If radRotorTop.Checked = True Then
        Pictype = "PicRotorTop"
    End If
    If radRotorBottom.Checked = True Then
        Pictype = "PicRotorBottom"
    End If
    If radDunnageFinal.Checked = True Then
        Pictype = "PicDunnageFinal"
    End If
    If radDunnageLayer.Checked = True Then
        Pictype = "PicDunnageLayer"
    End If
    If Not picSelectedPic.Image Is Nothing Then
        picSelectedPic.Image.Save("\\HOMESHARE01\Public\Reference Cards\Completed Reference Cards by Part Number" & "\" & FileName & "\" & lblRenameAs.Text & ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        MsgBox("Picture: " & lblRenameAs.Text & "        Was Saved In Folder: " & FileName)
    Else
        MsgBox("Please Select Picture Before Renaming")
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub Picture_Preview()
    Dim FileName As String = cmbPartNumber.Text
    Dim pics() As PictureBox
    Dim List() As String = Directory.GetFiles("\\HOMESHARE01\Public\Reference Cards\Completed Reference Cards by Part Number" & "\" & FileName, "*.jpg")

    If List.Length = "5" Then
        pics = {picPreview1, picPreview2, picPreview3, picPreview4, picPreview5}
    End If
    If List.Length = "4" Then
        pics = {picPreview1, picPreview2, picPreview3, picPreview4}
    End If
    If List.Length = "3" Then
        pics = {picPreview1, picPreview2, picPreview3}
    End If
    If List.Length = "2" Then
        pics = {picPreview1, picPreview2}
    End If
    If List.Length = "1" Then
        pics = {picPreview1}
    End If
    If List.Length = "0" Then
        MsgBox("No Pictures in File")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i As Integer = 0 To pics.Count - 1

        pics(i).Image = Image.FromFile(List(i))

    Next

    picPreview1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    picPreview2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    picPreview3.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    picPreview4.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    picPreview5.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    picSelectedPic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
End Sub

Private Sub picPreview1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picPreview1.Click
    picSelectedPic.Image = Nothing
    'Get the rectangle of the control and inflate it to represent the border area   
    Dim BorderBounds As Rectangle = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).ClientRectangle
    BorderBounds.Inflate(-1, -1)

    'Use ControlPaint to draw the border.   
    'Change the Color.Red parameter to your own colour below.   
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).CreateGraphics,
                                BorderBounds,
                                Color.Red,
                                ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)

    If Not (HighlightedPictureBox Is Nothing) Then
        'Remove the border of the last PictureBox   
        HighlightedPictureBox.Invalidate()
    End If

    'Rememeber the last highlighted PictureBox   
    HighlightedPictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)

    picSelectedPic.Image = picPreview1.Image
End Sub

Private Sub picPreview2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picPreview2.Click
    picSelectedPic.Image = Nothing
    'Get the rectangle of the control and inflate it to represent the border area   
    Dim BorderBounds As Rectangle = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).ClientRectangle
    BorderBounds.Inflate(-1, -1)

    'Use ControlPaint to draw the border.   
    'Change the Color.Red parameter to your own colour below.   
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).CreateGraphics,
                                BorderBounds,
                                Color.Red,
                                ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)

    If Not (HighlightedPictureBox Is Nothing) Then
        'Remove the border of the last PictureBox   
        HighlightedPictureBox.Invalidate()
    End If

    'Rememeber the last highlighted PictureBox   
    HighlightedPictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)

    picSelectedPic.Image = picPreview2.Image
End Sub

Private Sub picPreview3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picPreview3.Click
    picSelectedPic.Image = Nothing
    'Get the rectangle of the control and inflate it to represent the border area   
    Dim BorderBounds As Rectangle = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).ClientRectangle
    BorderBounds.Inflate(-1, -1)

    'Use ControlPaint to draw the border.   
    'Change the Color.Red parameter to your own colour below.   
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).CreateGraphics,
                                BorderBounds,
                                Color.Red,
                                ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)

    If Not (HighlightedPictureBox Is Nothing) Then
        'Remove the border of the last PictureBox   
        HighlightedPictureBox.Invalidate()
    End If

    'Rememeber the last highlighted PictureBox   
    HighlightedPictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)

    picSelectedPic.Image = picPreview3.Image
End Sub

Private Sub picPreview4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picPreview4.Click
    picSelectedPic.Image = Nothing
    'Get the rectangle of the control and inflate it to represent the border area   
    Dim BorderBounds As Rectangle = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).ClientRectangle
    BorderBounds.Inflate(-1, -1)

    'Use ControlPaint to draw the border.   
    'Change the Color.Red parameter to your own colour below.   
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).CreateGraphics,
                                BorderBounds,
                                Color.Red,
                                ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)

    If Not (HighlightedPictureBox Is Nothing) Then
        'Remove the border of the last PictureBox   
        HighlightedPictureBox.Invalidate()
    End If

    'Rememeber the last highlighted PictureBox   
    HighlightedPictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)

    picSelectedPic.Image = picPreview4.Image
End Sub

Private Sub picPreview5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picPreview5.Click
    picSelectedPic.Image = Nothing
    'Get the rectangle of the control and inflate it to represent the border area   
    Dim BorderBounds As Rectangle = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).ClientRectangle
    BorderBounds.Inflate(-1, -1)

    'Use ControlPaint to draw the border.   
    'Change the Color.Red parameter to your own colour below.   
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).CreateGraphics,
                                BorderBounds,
                                Color.Red,
                                ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)

    If Not (HighlightedPictureBox Is Nothing) Then
        'Remove the border of the last PictureBox   
        HighlightedPictureBox.Invalidate()
    End If

    'Rememeber the last highlighted PictureBox   
    HighlightedPictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)

    picSelectedPic.Image = picPreview5.Image
End Sub

Private Sub radRotorTop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radRotorTop.Click
    Dim FileName As String = cmbPartNumber.Text
    Pictype = "PicRotorTop"
    lblRenameAs.Text = Pictype & FileName
End Sub

Private Sub radRotorBottom_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radRotorBottom.Click
    Dim FileName As String = cmbPartNumber.Text
    Pictype = "PicRotorBottom"
    lblRenameAs.Text = Pictype & FileName
End Sub

Private Sub radDunnageLayer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radDunnageLayer.Click
    Dim FileName As String = cmbPartNumber.Text
    Pictype = "PicDunnageLayer"
    lblRenameAs.Text = Pictype & FileName
End Sub

Private Sub radDunnageFinal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radDunnageFinal.Click
    Dim FileName As String = cmbPartNumber.Text
    Pictype = "PicDunnageFinal"
    lblRenameAs.Text = Pictype & FileName
End Sub

Private Sub radSpindle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radSpindle.Click
    Dim FileName As String = cmbPartNumber.Text
    Pictype = "PicSpindle"
    lblRenameAs.Text = Pictype & FileName
End Sub

Private Sub btnPurgeFolder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPurgeFolder.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

GetFiles Code:

```
 Public Sub Picture_Preview()
Dim FileName As String = cmbPartNumber.Text
Dim pics() As PictureBox
Dim List() As String = Directory.GetFiles("\\HOMESHARE01\Public\Reference Cards\Completed Reference Cards by Part Number" & "\" & FileName, "*.jpg")

If List.Length = "5" Then
    pics = {picPreview1, picPreview2, picPreview3, picPreview4, picPreview5}
End If
If List.Length = "4" Then
    pics = {picPreview1, picPreview2, picPreview3, picPreview4}
End If
If List.Length = "3" Then
    pics = {picPreview1, picPreview2, picPreview3}
End If
If List.Length = "2" Then
    pics = {picPreview1, picPreview2}
End If
If List.Length = "1" Then
    pics = {picPreview1}
End If
If List.Length = "0" Then
    MsgBox("No Pictures in File")
    Exit Sub
End If

For i As Integer = 0 To pics.Count - 1

    pics(i).Image = Image.FromFile(List(i))

Next

picPreview1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
picPreview2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
picPreview3.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
picPreview4.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
picPreview5.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
picSelectedPic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to look through. By "These pictures that are being saved will always contain these words," do you mean the *filenames* of those pictures?

Comment: Incidentally, `Image.Save` as a jpeg can give disappointing results. You might want to look at [Image.Save Method (String, ImageCodecInfo, EncoderParameters)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use a higher quality setting (like 80&).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, you should generally favor `EnumerateFiles()` over `GetFiles()` especially if you want to filter the results.  This uses a helper function to filter out the ones you don't want:

```
Dim txFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\Temp", "*.*",
                                 System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
                             Where(Function(q) IncludeFile(q)).ToArray()
```

Helper function to filter them:

```
Private Function IncludeFile(f As String) As Boolean
    Dim exclude() = {"PicSpindle", "PicRotor", "PicFoo"}
    Dim filepart As String

    For Each s In exclude
        filepart = Path.GetFileName(f)

        If filepart.StartsWith(s, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

You will have to fiddle with the exclusion logic depending on the details...I cant find your `GetFiles` in that wall of code to check it.

Comment: lol sorry, last time I ask a question someone on here gave me a hard time because I didn't put all my code. I updated the question so it sections out the `GetFiles` sub. And thanks ill try using Helper.

Comment: Works pretty well! I had to change some logic but yeah it works, thanks!